# HashMap repeating the last element

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to create a `HashMap` in a `HashMap` so it will be easier for me to access elements of it in the future as shown below.

The problem is it only repeating the last elements of the `while` loop and not the rest of it.

```
HashMap<String,String> result = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String,String>> fr = new HashMap<>();

int i = 0;
try {
    ResultSet rq = qexec.execSelect();
    // ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, rq, query);

    // get result from SPARQL query
    while (rq.hasNext()) {
        QuerySolution soln = rq.next();
        id = soln.getLiteral("?id").getLexicalForm();
        //...
        result.put("id",id);
        //...
        if (soln.getLiteral("?wateruse") != null) {
            wateruse = soln.getLiteral("?wateruse").getLexicalForm();
            //...
            result.put("wateruse",wateruse);
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO");
        }               

        fr.put(i, result);
        i++;
    }
} finally {
    qexec.close();
}
```

This is how the result should be:

```
John001
High usage
John002
John003
Smith001
Moderate
Smith002
Smith003
...
Kevin001
Low usage
```

But `fr` only repeats `Kevin001` and `Low usage` without the rest.

I've tried to put `fr.put(i,result)` outside the loop but that still does not give the correct result.

**EDIT**

I tried to print all elements from `fr` that shows the repeating elements.

```
finally {

            qexec.close();
        }


        for (int index : fr.keySet()) {
              for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry :result.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(index + " = " + entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE - SOLUTION**

Declare `HashMap` inside the loop as mentioned in comments below.

To print nested HashMap, no need to use `result`. 
I did as shown below and it prints both `outermap` and `innermap` as well.

```js
        for (int k=0;  k < fr.size(); k++) {
            HashMap<String,String> innermap = fr.get(k);
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> e : innermap.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(k + " = " + e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue());
            }
        }
```

Comment: creating map object inside loop will solve you problem. like : result = new HashMap<>();

Comment: In your edit to print all elements, you should not be using "result.entryset" (which has nothing to do with the outer for loop), but "fr.get(index)"

Comment: You're printing the values from the last entry in the map because you're printing the `result` map. That will always have the data from the last iteration through the loop. Instead, get the values from `fr` as you loop through it (updated with details on how to do that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding the same `result` map to your parent map each time through the loop. Create a new instance of `result` each time through the loop:

```
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> fr = new HashMap<>();

int i = 0;
try {

    ResultSet rq = qexec.execSelect();

    while (rq.hasNext()) {

        // Create your new HashMap inside the loop:
        result = new HashMap<>();

        QuerySolution soln = rq.next();

        id = soln.getLiteral("?id").getLexicalForm();
        //...

        result.put("id",id);
        //...

        if (soln.getLiteral("?wateruse") != null) {

            wateruse = soln.getLiteral("?wateruse").getLexicalForm();
            //...
            result.put("wateruse",wateruse);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("NO");
        }               

        fr.put(i,result);
        i++;
    }
}
```

To print the results from `fr` an its nested map, you can do something like this:

```
for (Map<String, String> map : fr.values()) {
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(index + " = " + e.getKey() 
            + " : " + e.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you highlight the part in the code where you have changed something?

Comment: Hmm I tried that but the result still repeating.

Comment: where does `index` comes from in `System.out.println(index + " = " + e.getKey() `?

Answer (score 2):

Try this a small change here, place the "result" map creation in while loop

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> fr = new HashMap<>();

int i = 0;
try {

    ResultSet rq = qexec.execSelect();

    while (rq.hasNext()) {
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();

        QuerySolution soln = rq.next();

        id = soln.getLiteral("?id").getLexicalForm();
        //...

        result.put("id",id);
        //...

        if (soln.getLiteral("?wateruse") != null) {

            wateruse = soln.getLiteral("?wateruse").getLexicalForm();
            //...
            result.put("wateruse",wateruse);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("NO");
        }               

        fr.put(i,result);
        i++;
    }
}
```

This for loop to print elemenets:

```
for (int i=0;i< fr.size();i++){
    Map<String,String> element= fr.get(i);
//  use the element here.

}
```

Comment: But then I cannot access `result` from outside the loop.

Comment: @kaixasK You shouldn't be using `result` outside of the loop anyway. After the loop it will only have the last value. What are you using that for?

Comment: Then you can declare the object outside loop and in loop create new element `result = new HashMap<>();` But why do you need result object outside loop, you have the "fr" already available to you to access all elements.

Comment: How can I do so since it is `HashMap` in another `HashMap`?

Comment: @kaixasK see my edited answer please.